# MemoryProxy me.model is undefined error

Tags: extjs, proxy, extjs4, store, extjs4.1

I'm getting an error like I added below while using static data with memory proxy. 
Can someone show me my mistake or missing part?

Thanks in advance.

```
me.model is undefined
me.setProxy(me.proxy || me.model.getProxy());
```

My model definition:

```
Ext.define(appName + '.model.Country', {    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {type: 'string', name: 'abbr'},
        {type: 'string', name: 'name'},
        {type: 'string', name: 'slogan'}
    ]
});
```

And here's my store definition:

```
// The data for all states
var data = {
    states : [
        {'abbr':'AL','name':'Alabama','slogan':'The Heart of Dixie'},
        {'abbr':'AK','name':'Alaska','slogan':'The Land of the Midnight Sun'}
    ]
};


Ext.define(appName + '.store.Countries', {
    extend        : 'Ext.data.Store',
    model        : appName + '.model.Country',
    data        : data,
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'states'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Where is exactly you do call me.setProxy? And why are you using dynamic class names (appName +)?

Comment: I'm using Ext JS 4.1 and using dymanic loading, so the controller calls the proxy. appName is a constant variable. There's no mistake while using same config with Ajax Proxies.(I've other stores that uses the same model)

Comment: No. Where is the code that calls setProxy? Is it in your controller? or in the basic ExtJs store class?

Comment: it's in store class; basically done with setting autoLoad:true.

Comment: Add some log inside store class to see if it getting model string and if it able to construct model properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check if the model file is actually loaded and available for usage. When dealing with a large number of files, ExtJS (I have encountered this while working with 4.2.1) has problems with ordering them.

A quick fix is using **requires:** in the application definition:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'APP',
    appFolder: 'application',

    controllers: [
    ...
    ],
    requires: ['APP.model.examples', 'APP.model.other' ...],
    ...
});
```

If this helps, I have written more on a PHP solution here:

[Solution for ExtJS 4 me.model is undefined error](http://blog.draghici.net/solution-for-extjs-4-me-model-is-undefined-error/)

Comment: In order to avoid the error above, you could also use: `requires: [<list of models used in the component>]`. This should save you the hustle of identlifying all the models and loading them in the app definition.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create the store explicitly and specify it in the config of the container?

For example:

```
var store = Ext.create(appName + '.store.Countries');
Ext.create('Your Component', {
    ...
    store: store,
    ...
});
```